# dimple tickFormat ignores grouping comma

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

I have a dimple chart displaying some large numbers. I want the precise values to appear in the toolbox (not truncated to 14k) so I changed the `tickFormat`. However, dimple/d3 seems to ignore the grouping comma, which makes large numbers hard to process.

```
// this prints "12,345" as expected
var f = d3.format(",.0f");
console.log(f(12345.123));

var data = [{"date":"2016-01-18","completed":1234123.100},{"date":"2016-01-19","completed":1345123.0},{"date":"2016-01-20","completed":2123123.1}]

var svg = dimple.newSvg("#foo", "100%", "100%");
var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
var x = myChart.addTimeAxis("x", "date", "%Y-%m-%d", "%d/%m");
var y = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "completed");

// this does not work
// tooltips and y axis values appear without grouping comma
y.tickFormat = d3.format(",.0f");
myChart.setMargins("60px", "30px", "30px", "70px");
series = myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.line);
myChart.draw();
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the API documentation the property [`dimple.axis.tickFormat`](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.axis#tickFormat) will accept the format specifier string (i.e. `",.0f"`). as it is passed to `d3.format()`. You don't have to call `d3.format()` yourself; this is done internally in function [`_getFormat()`](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/blob/master/src/objects/axis/methods/_getFormat.js). Thus your code becomes

```
y.tickFormat = ",.0f";
```